# What do I list for countries visited question in U.S customs Declaration form (U.S)

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration

While reading about the customs declaration form I saw  there is a question, "countries visited on this trip prior to U.S. arrival".

Do we have to mention all the countries I visited previously? for example, back in 2020, 2019, and 2018, I visited few European countries(Sweden, Denmark, Germany, Poland, U.K, and France). Do I need to mention them?

I am flying from India to the U.S.A directly. What do I have to mention in the form? Only India or should I also mention the countries I have mentioned above?

Comment: They’re asking about countries visited *on this trip*, not about your entire travel history prior to it.

Answer (score 21):

The answer is in the material you quoted:

> countries visited **on this trip** prior to U.S. arrival

If you flew directly from your home country to the US, the answer to this question is "none".

Sometimes, when applying for visas and such, you have to list all your travel for as long as ten years. But this question is far more specific.

Comment: @VatsavVarma If this answer helped, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark. That lets other people know this answer's correct, and helps out the answerer a little.